# System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .netframework

Estoy trabajando en un cotizador, los precios de cada productos los saco de una base de datos externa.
Cuando la conecto con lo ingresado en el front y comparo la información, me tira esa excepción.

La clase que uso para cargar la información se llama "BeltsRollos" y toma datos "varchar" en el caso de los string y "float" en el caso de los float:

```
    public class BeltsRollo
{
    // public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Material {  get; set; }
    public string Descripcion {  get; set; }
    public string Moneda {  get; set; }
    public float Costo {  get; set; }

}
```

Acá llamo a la bd desde el código de la aplicación

```
    while (lector.Read())
{
    BeltsRollo aux = new BeltsRollo();
    aux.Material = "Material";
    while (material_seleccionado.Material != aux.Material){
        
        aux.Material = (string)lector["Material"];

        if (aux.Material == material_seleccionado.Material)
        {
            // material_seleccionado.Id = (string)lector["Id"];
            material_seleccionado.Material = aux.Material;
            material_seleccionado.Descripcion = (string)lector["Descripcion"];
            material_seleccionado.Moneda = (string)lector["Moneda"];
            material_seleccionado.Costo = (float)lector["Costo"];
        }
    }
}
```

Y acá es donde quiero usarla. Todo esto, salvo la clase BeltsRollos, está dentro de un bloque Try.

```
 string material = material_seleccionado.Material;
 int ancho = int.Parse(valAncho.Text);
 int desarrollo = int.Parse(valDesarrollo.Text);
 string terminacion = txtTerminacion.Text;
 string descripcion = "CORREA " + material + " - " + ancho + " X " + desarrollo + " " + terminacion;

 lblDescripcion.Text = descripcion;
```

No encuentro el error en el código, alguno puede ayudarme?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Probablemente es el float,  que tipo de datos tiene `Costo` en la base de datos?

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).